# tkinter 8.6 still doesn't support png files?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I use `python 3.7.9` on Windows. `tkinter` version is 8.6.

I am following [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WurCpmHtQc4&t=230s), and trying to use `.png` image as a GUI background.
When I run **#1**, it throws an error. When I run **#2**, it works fine.

[Official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#images) says :

> - PhotoImage for images in PGM, PPM, GIF and PNG formats. The latter is supported starting with Tk 8.6.

I found similar questions asked years ago, but that was when `tkinter` had not yet supported `.png` and they advised to use `PIL`.

I checked my `tkinter` version and it says 8.6, anyone could enlighten me what the problem is here?
Is the use of `PIL` still officially required to handle `png`?

On a side note, exact same error raised for **#1** when I replaced `.png` with `.gif` as well.

---

#### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4a440c40f4bf> in <module>
      4 root = Tk()
      5 
----> 6 bg = PhotoImage(file='test.png')
      7 bg_label = Label(root, image=bg)
      8 bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

~\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, cnf, master, **kw)
   3543         Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette,
   3544         width."""
-> 3545         Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
   3546     def blank(self):
   3547         """Display a transparent image."""

~\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, imgtype, name, cnf, master, **kw)
   3499                 v = self._register(v)
   3500             options = options + ('-'+k, v)
-> 3501         self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
   3502         self.name = name
   3503     def __str__(self): return self.name

TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "test.png"
```

#### #1

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

bg = PhotoImage(file='test.png')
bg_label = Label(root, image=bg)
bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

#### #2

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
bg_label = Label(root, image=bg)
bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is a png file? Could it be some other format that got renamed to .png?

Comment: @DapperDuck the difference is .png and .gif and from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Comment: @Bryan, thanks for your comment. Came to think about it, the original was .`jpg`. I converted it to png. Changing the extension doesn't change the format itself...?

Comment: Of course changing file extension does not change the format.  Use image processing application to convert it (like `convert` from `ImageMagick`).  Or use Pillow module which will auto detect the image format.

Comment: @koyamashinji no, it won't. The extension is just part of the filename, a comment for humans. Most programs ignore the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkinter` version 8.6 does support `.png` iamges.

The reason it wasn't working was the image I thought was a `.png` file was actually not a `.png` file. I downloaded the image originally as a `.jpg` file and I simply changed the extension. **Changing extensions does not change the file type itself.**

I grabbed other `.png` image and it worked fine.